# Tkinter 'quit' button must be pressed repeatedly for multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a Tkinter GUI that displays matplotlib figures. I use the variable 'window' to initialize the Tk interpreter; instead of 'root' / 'main' = Tk(). The GUI is formatted by the class MyWindow.

```
class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, win):
```

Three GUI 'visual' buttons display matplotlib figures. The functions for the mpl figures are in a module called 'charts'. In the below example, 'overview' is a visual button.

```
        self.btn5=Button(win, text='Overview')
        self.b5=Button(win, text='Overview', width='6', height='2', command=self.overview)
        self.b5.place(x=50, y=160)

    def overview(self):
        from charts import overview
        overview()
```

A 'quit' button exits the visual windows and the GUI itself. Quit button code:

```
        self.btn6=Button(win, text='Quit')
        self.b6=Button(win, text='Quit', width='6', height='2', command=window.quit)
        self.b6.place(x=50, y=230)

    def quit(self):
        self.win.destroy()
```

All features work as intended, barring the 'quit' button. I must click 'quit' as many times as the number of windows the GUI opened for it to work.

**i.e. I launch the GUI and open the 'overview' visual; I need to click 'quit' twice to close 'overview' and the GUI itself.**

I've tried adjusting both the quit button 'command' and the quit function to all combinations of  destroy() / quit() with prefixes self, win, and window (and no prefix).

Comment: I'm guessing you either have two root windows or call `mainloop` more than once. Though there are other possible reasons. Please edit your question to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: The issue has been solved. @Aleksander Ikleiw figured it out, thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Python` inbuilt function called `quit()` it will just quit the program killing its processes.

```
def quit(self):
    quit()
```